# Repository Pattern Design for a ASP MVC app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, design-patterns, architecture, repository-pattern, data-access-layer

This is more of a design concern.

Im building an app and i have created my Repository Pattern Structure as following :

My Core name space is the DAL/Repository/BusinessLogic layers assembly.

By the way, i am using Dapper.NET micro ORM as my data connection, thats why you will see an extension on my SqlConnection object.

For my data access, i have created a base repository class :

```
namespace Core
{
    public class BaseRepository<T>: IDisposable where T : BaseEntity 
    {
        protected SqlConnection conn = null;


        #region Constructors
        public BaseRepository() : this("LOCAL")
        {

        }

        public BaseRepository(string configurationKey = "LOCAL")
        {
            conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[configurationKey].ConnectionString);
        }
        #endregion

        #region IDisposable
        public void Dispose()
        {
            conn.Dispose();
        }
        #endregion


        /// <summary>
        /// returns a list of entities
        /// </summary>
        /// <typeparam name="T">BaseEntity type</typeparam>
        /// <param name="sproc">optional parameters, stored procedure name.</param>
        /// <returns>BaseEntity</returns>
        protected virtual IEnumerable<T> GetListEntity(string sproc = null)
        {
            string storedProcName = string.Empty;
            if (sproc == null)
            {
                storedProcName = "[dbo].sp_GetList_" + typeof(T).ToString().Replace("Core.",string.Empty);
            }
            else
            {
                storedProcName = sproc;
            }

            IEnumerable<T> items = new List<T>();
            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                items = conn.Query<T>(storedProcName,
                                                     commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
                conn.Close();
            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }


            return items;
        }


    }
}
```

And for each entity that I  have, lets say ExtendedUser, Messages , i am creating its on Interface-Class pair like this :

```
namespace Core
{
    public class ExtendedUserRepository : BaseRepository<UsersExtended>,IExtendedUserRepository
    {

        public ExtendedUserRepository() : this("PROD") 
        {
        }

        public ExtendedUserRepository(string configurationKey) : base(configurationKey)
        {
        }


        public UsersExtended GetExtendedUser(string username)
        {
            var list = GetListEntity().SingleOrDefault(u => u.Username == username);
            return list;
        }

        public UsersExtended GetExtendedUser(Guid userid)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }


        public List<UsersExtended> GetListExtendedUser()
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
}
```

etc.

The above code is just one of the entities :ExtendedUser.

The question is : should i create a Interface-ClassThatImplemenetsInterface pair for each entity that i have ? or should i have only one RepositoryClass and one IRepository interface with all my methods from all of my entities?

Comment: I'd go with a generic repository, which you've (almost) already got:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need to create interface without the reason. I even don't see why you need base repository class here. I even think this is not repository but DAL (Data Access Layer) but this is defintion argue.

I think good DAL implementation should decouple database structure from business logic structure - but hardcoding sp_GetList_XXXEntityNameXXX pattern or passing stored procedure name outside of DAL is not decoupling.

You are very optimistic or your application is really simple if you think all entity lists are obtained in one way and you will always need full set of entities in business logic without any parameters.

Separating interface from implementation is only needed if you plan to replace/wrap out different implementations, or mix few interfaces in one class. Otherwise it is not required.

Don't think in terms of entities when creating repositories. Repository contains business logic and should be built over scenarios of usage. Having classes like you have is more about Data Access Layer - and DAL is built over queries you would need in business logic. Probably you would never need list of ALL users at once - but would very often need list of active users, privileged users etc.

It is really hard to predict what queries you will need - so I prefer to start designing from business logic and add DAL methods by the way.

Comment: "Repository contains business logic and should be built over scenarios of usage" - why do you say that? Shouldn't the concern of the repository be just moving data in and out? Shouldn't the business logic have its own place/layer/classes?

Comment: It depends on names - I agree with you about separating data access and business logic classes. I've named classes for business logic 'repositories' - may be it can be confusing. Sometimes it called services etc.

Comment: And an interface is useful on the repository class in order to unit test the controller or whoever will be calling the repository...

Comment: However I really agree with "It is really hard to predict what queries you will need - so I prefer to start designing from business logic and add DAL methods by the way."

Comment: thanks for the reply @STO. Point taken, I understand what you mean here. The whole "Repository" Interface idea is to support unit testing better but I should start from the business logic layer

Answer (score 1):

> A system with a complex domain model often benefits from a layer, such
>   as the one provided by Data Mapper (165), that isolates domain objects
>   from details of the database access code. In such systems it can be
>   worthwhile to build another layer of abstraction over the mapping
>   layer where query construction code is concentrated.
>
> http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html

With a generic repository you can have common methods like `findBy(array('id' => 1))`, `findOneBy(array('email' => 'john@bar.com'))`, `findById()`, `findAll()` and so on. Indeed, it'll have one interface.

You'll always have to create a concrete implementation that will indicates which is the domain object that will  be managed by the repository in order to accomplish this `getUsersRepository().findAll()`

Moreover, if you need more complicated queries, you can create new methods on the concrete implementation, such as `findMostActiveUsers()` and then reuse it across your application.

**Now, answering your question:**

Your application will be expecting for at least one interface (that generic one, with the common methods). But if you manage to have specific methods, like the one I've just mentioned above, you'd be better having another interface (e.g. RepositoryInterface and UsersRepositoryInteface).

With that in mind, then you'll only depend on the repository interface. The query construction will be encapsulated by the concrete implementation. So you'll be able to change your repository implementation (e.g. using an full-blow ORM) without affecting the rest of your application.